# Pulseaudio stops youtube playback when bluetooth A2DP headset connected

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and pulseaudio is installed.

When I connect to bluetooth A2DP headset, the video playback on YouTube (google-chrome) stops with message:

> if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device.

If I remove or disconnect from the bluetooth headset, the video will start playing again immediately.

I added `Disable=socket` in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` and that solved the problem. I also found some different bluetooth A2DP issues have the same solution, but there is no explanation.

Why does disabling the socket fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.lightofdawn.org/blog/?viewDetailed=00031) is an article about bluez I found.

It said that the option `Enable=Socket` in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` enables the `audio socket API` of bluez. The `ALSA PCM plugin` talks to bluez using this socket interface and it is already deprecated for sometime.

Also it mentioned that bluez cannot handle the d-bus API correctly when the socket interface is enabled.

So this might explain why pulseaudio would not work properly with bluetooth when `Disable=socket` is removed from `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`.